# JsonResult in MVC3 app need to add a default entry at top of results...

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, var

I need to insert a default value at the top of the result I have as below....

Can someone give me a clue how to do it with an anonymous type?

```
public JsonResult GetThingsForStuff(string stuff)
    {
        var things= from c in db.MYTABLE
                         where c.idofstuff == stuff
                         select new { id = c.realid, name = c.realname};
        return Json(things, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my controller I do this initially by

```
List<SelectListItem> items3 = new SelectList(db.MYTABLE.ToList().Distinct(), "realid", "realname").ToList();
        items3.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Me", Value = "0" }));
        ViewBag.Things = items3;
```

by I have a javascript function reloading this dropdownlist based on the selected "stuff" and I need this default back at the top.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate them:

```
public JsonResult GetThingsForStuff(string stuff)
{
    var things = db
        .MYTABLE
        .Where(x => x.idofstuff == stuff)
        .ToList()
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.realid.ToString(),
            Text = x.realname
        });

    var items = new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Me", Value = "0" } }
        .Concat(things);

    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```